# Ошибка в выборке

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT `school` . `street` FROM `datacenter`, `school` WHERE `datacenter` . `id_school` = `school` . `id_school` AND `datacenter` . `name` = "Антон"');
```

`echo $result;` - выводит resourse id. Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала - вам [сюда](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php)     сдесь тоже есть вывод выборки из бд
Внимательно прочтите доку по функции и вы обнаружите что `mysql_query` возвращает значение типа `resourse`. Для того чтобы преобразовать эти данные например в массив необходимо использовать что-то из этого mysql_fetch, mysql_fetch_row, mysql_fetch_assoc. О разнице вы всегда можете узнать на [php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/)

В вашем конкретном случае:

```
$dbResult = mysql_query('SELECT `school` . `street` FROM `datacenter`, `school` WHERE `datacenter` . `id_school` = `school` . `id_school` AND `datacenter` . `name` = "Антон"');
$resultArray = array();

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $dbResult ) ) {
    $resultArray[] = $row;
}
//    по заверению работы цикла все значение выборки
//    лежат в $resultArray
//    и да, чтобы выводить массив нельзя использовать echo
print_r($resultArray);    //    выведем полученый результат
```

PS: Подозреваю что вам неплохо было бы начать все-таки с книги "серии" "php for dummies", благо для вас - таких книг на просторах сети предостаточно...

Comment: php for dummies нет раздела работа с БД

Comment: Да но если бы книга была бы нормальной - вы бы поняли что когда выводится `resource` - Значит эти данные еще как-то надо обработать.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что это ресурс! Данные надо доставать отдельно.

```
$res = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
 ...
}
```